# When using the fancyhdr package, the header part repeats on every page on Latex. How can I avoid repetition as I want header only on 1st page?

Tags: overleaf

I employed the use of "data-science-tech-resume-template" template on overleaf for building my own resume. The "_header.tex" file contains the use of 'fancyhdr' package and used lheader and rheader to display my name, email id, contact, etc. However, this header part repeats on every page.
[image: Page1]

[image: Page2]

Below is the code for _header.tex:

```
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{

        \HUGE \skills \name \vspace{-.32em}
        \\ % feel free to adjust vspace to 0 
    {
            \color{highlight} \Large{\role}
        }
} 
\rhead{
    
        \city \\  % city 
        \phone \\ % PHONE    
        \href{mailto:\email}{\email} \\
        % \href{https://github.com/\github}{github.com/\github} \\% Github
        \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/\LinkedIn}{linkedin.com/in/\LinkedIn}
} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}% 2pt header rule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
\color{highlight}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\headheight}{90pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want, the sole purpose of the fancyhdr commands is to specify text that appears at the top of every page, so what you describe sounds like the expected result.

Comment: I suppose you could use `\pagestyle{empty} \thispagestyle{plain}` so you only get that page style on the first page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried the command you mentioned, but it displays blank instead of the header part. What I am expecting is that the header area which has my name and other information only appears on the 1st page and doesn't appear on the following pages. Do I need to use some other command or completely avoid using **lhead** and **rhead** commands entirely?

Comment: as your question has no example it's not clear what you want, but it sounds like you want the text yo be simply entered as text on the first page, not a header at all

Comment: To give a brief understanding, I have attached 2 pictures - 1st and 2nd page of my resume. The header part where my name and social media accounts are visible is getting replicated on the 2nd page as well which I would like to avoid. Since I am new to Latex, I am not sure of the syntax but want to display it as appears on the 1st page and avoid repeating in the next pages.

Comment: then do as I suggest in the second comment above